# Cordova | Unable to add the Android platform using `cordova platform add android`

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm following the steps given in http://chrislarson.me/blog/how-use-cordova-ubuntu-build-android-apps.html
to build my first app for Android on Ubuntu.

But when I run this: `cordova platform add android`, I get the following message on the terminal:

> Error: EACCES, open
>   '/home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/.npmignore'

If i try running `sudo cordova platform add android`, I get

> Creating android project...
>
> /home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^
>   Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
>       at /home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:159:19
>       at _fulfilled (/home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
>       at /home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
>       at flush (/home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:929:3
>   Error: /home/a/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)

Comment: Is your path is correct? and Please can you confirm it by typing android in terminal and see whether your getting SDK manager?

Comment: I type in `android` and it says `command not found`

Comment: see that’s your problem. I think /home/a/Developm‌​ent/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk is not your sdk path. can you verify it?

Comment: I think my problem is understanding environment variables in Linux. Based on the output of my `echo $PATH` , please could you advice how to set up the path?

Comment: remove old paths and add these to your bashrc `export ANDROID_HOME=your sdk path
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms-tools`  and after that use `source ~/.bashrc` to execute bashrc file

Comment: Done but same problem! Sorry..

Comment: whats your system username is it 'a'?

Comment: @Muthu. Yes Its 'a'.

Comment: @Muthu Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you confirm the path '/home/a/Developm‌​ent/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk' physically? since I am not sure the path is right.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the contents of

```
.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/
```

and then try again.

cordova / npm cache cordova-android files deleting these will ensure a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

first check your android path by echo $ANDROID_HOME
then if it is showing path then you have set ANDROID_HOME path correctly and 
if not then do this
1) sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
2) then paste following path at the last of file save it and close.

export ANDROID_HOME=your_sdk_path/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

your first error is permission issue and second because ANDROID_HOME path not set correctly